# My customer still see old version of the APP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

at the first place, we hosted our React App on the S3 to which we assigned CloudFront distribution and then we connected it to *somedomain.com*  domain.

The thing is that for marketing tests we had to change A-record in Route53 to point to a totally different server than AWS. So the problem is that some of the users already used our React App with ServiceWorker that was hosted on S3, and even that we changed A-records to point to different server - they still see AWS cached version.

We have no idea where is the problem, and if we should change something in Route 53 or Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this before, but don't have a good explanation as to why it happened.

I had to remove the domain from the CloudFront distribution before I got all traffic being sent correctly to the new record in Route 53.

After removing the domain from the CloudFront config, traffic immediately started being sent to the value in the A record in Route 53.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait also for the support of AWS, or maybe someone else came across an issue like we did and have some good explanation for it. If not, I'll definitely try it.
Cheers!